# How to get an image from file input and send it to NodeJS Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, file-upload, image-uploading

I have tried several things to get my image data from the file input and send it to the NodeJS server but nothing has helped me so far. I had a lot of different solutions with formData, FileReader etc. but I never had my data.

My HTML is following:

```
<button type="button" id="uploadButton" onclick="openFilepicker()">
Upload file
</button>
```

The openFilepicker() function triggers a click via jQuery on the file-input element:

```
<form id='uploadForm' encType="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="uploader" class="hidden" 
    id="input-file" onchange="submitUploadForm()"/>
</form>
```

The submitUploadForm() function gets executed when a file has been selected:

```
function submitUploadForm() {
  if ($('#input-file').val() != '') {
    const input = document.getElementById('input-file');
    const file = input.files[0];

    /* Process my data here to be ready to send it */

    $.ajax({
        url: '/upload',
        type: 'POST',
        data: '', /* Here I want my file data to be sent */
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }.bind(this),
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }.bind(this)
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously) because it did not work for me.

Comment: Just because it doesn't work for you doesn't mean it's not the correct answer. You need to upload the binary file data using a `FormData` object, exactly as the duplicate shows. You can then deal with it on the server as needed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Logging my FormData Obj shows an empty Obj {} - so I'm not able to fill it

Comment: You cannot view the content of a FormData object in the console as it's binary. It will have been filled correctly though

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that, I was stuck all the time at that point trying to figure out why it's empty, now I just handled it on the server and it is actually filled correctly, thanks